# RIA application for Android and Windows in JavaFX

Tags: android, windows, javafx, ria

I want to create a RIA application that will work on android tablet and under windows. Does the JavaFX technology allow to do that? Clearly i want to deal with only one code.
Moreover, will the JavaFX technology allow me do build a design close to those adapted for Android tablet.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one JavaFX application and have it run on multiple supported devices.

An example of how you can do it from javafxports.org/page/Getting_Started

> Android:
>
> You need:
>
> ```
> your JavaFX application, built as a jar, in
> ```
>
> e.g. /path/to/your/app/yourapplication.jar.
>
> The resulting application
>   should be in Java 7 (or Java 6) class format
>       all libraries you depend on, in the same directory. These libraries should contain Java 6/7 classes as well (no Java 8 for now)
>       The Android SDK, in /path/to/androidSDK. Download this from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download
>       The JavaFX Dalvik SDK, which can be obtained at https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/android/downloads/dalvik-sdk-b10.zip
>       The Grade and ant build systems
>
> Currently, two additional steps are required. In the first step, you
>   create an Android Project based on your JavaFX classes. In the second
>   step, you compile the Android Project into an APK.
>
> 1. Create an Android Project
>
> The JavaFX Dalvik SDK you downloaded contains a directory
>   android-tools. This directory contains a gradle buildscript
>   (build.gradle) that allows to create an Android Project. You need to
>   supply a number of parameters which are documented in the build.gradle
>   file. A createHelloWorld.sh script also shows how to use the
>   parameters. One of the parameters is DIR, which point to the directory
>   where the Android Project will be created.
>
> 2. The Android Project is created in a directory DIR/. It contains an ant build.xml file that will build the Android Package by calling
>
> ant debug
>
> The result of this process is  -debug.apk file in the bin directory of
>   the created directory. You can run this apk on an Android emulator, or
>   easier, transfer it to an Android device using
>   /path/to/androidSDK/platform-tools/adb install bin/-debug.apk

As for your second question, you would be able to build an adapted design for Android tablets, however that would involve you to tweak a few things in the android application.